# Removing text after `:`, `:` included

Tags: java, strings

I need to remove last text after `:` in my String and `:` too. I have tried this. Please review. If there is a better way to do, please tell me.

```
String test = "temp:content:region:deposit:up";
System.out.println(test.replace(test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(":"), test.length()), ""));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using regexp (replace) isn't the best solution. I think you should use only substring:

```
System.out.println(test.substring(0, test.lastIndexOf(":")))
```